# Change the store api from controller in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

The below is my `MyStore.js`:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.MyStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'MyApp.model.Note',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            /* I want to change the following two filepaths */
            read: 'data/notesMar2013.json',
            update: 'data/notesMar2013.json' 
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data',
            successProperty: 'success'
        }
    }
});
```

I am trying to change the `read` and `update` values in `api` of MyStore through controller as follows:

```
var notesStore = Ext.getStore('MyStore');
notesStore.on('load',function(notesStore){
        var proxy = notesStore.getProxy();
        Ext.apply(proxy.api,{
            /* Changing the file paths here */
            read: 'data/notesApr2013.json',
            update: 'data/notesApr2013.json' 
        })
        notesStore.load();                              
},this,{single:false});
//
console.log(notesStore);
```

By using the above function, I am trying to update MyStore but it is not happening. When I checked in chrome console the values are changed successfully but not updating or overriding the store even I used `notesStore.load()`. What could be the problem?

I referred the below links

- [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7670001/1577396)
- [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8025687/1577396)

**Answer**:  The code was working fine. Let me explain my problem: I was showing the contents from the store on a container and initially, the container was filled with some content and the height was fixed. If I even add any content to the container then it will become hidden as the container is with fixed height. Till now, the content was being **appended** to the default content instead of removing the default content and then adding. That was the actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work without any problem, hence you have a error at any other point. Please take a look at the console in this **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R8Tzp/)**. In here's the test-code I used

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Note',{extend:'Ext.data.Model'});
Ext.define('MyApp.store.MyStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'MyApp.model.Note',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        getUrl: function(request) {
            console.log('fetched request url');
            console.log(this.api[request.action]);
            return request.url || this.api[request.action] || this.url;
        },
        api: {
            /* I want to change the following two filepaths */
            read: 'data/notesMar2013.json',
            update: 'data/notesMar2013.json' 
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data',
            successProperty: 'success'
        }
    }
});
var store = Ext.create('MyApp.store.MyStore');
console.log('The origin API');
console.log(store.getProxy().api);
store.load();
var proxy = store.getProxy();
var newApi =  {read: 'data/2013.json', update: 'data/2013.json' };
Ext.apply(proxy.api,newApi);
console.log('The changed API');
console.log(store.getProxy().api);
store.load();
```

Comment: Thanks for response. Yes my code is changing the variables but not updating the old store (It is showing the same values as you are showing in fiddle but unable to update or override the old store). Anyway, I will look at other point as you suggested.

Comment: @Mr_Green Please note that I make an instance override of the `getUrl: function(request)` method from the proxy to fetch the url the proxy will use for this request. But you can also see in the failed request, that the store used the correct api, even after the change

Comment: I just copied your code into my project. still it is not updating or overriding. It seems I am doing some silly mistake here as always.

Comment: @Mr_Green Yes you are ;) ! `console.log(notesStore);` need to be within the event-callback!! place it right after the `Ext.apply` and you should see the correct output.

Comment: Arghhh.. silly mistake. Actually, my function was working fine. The problem was that the contents were being **appended** to the container instead of clearing and then adding new contents. As the newly added contents were appending below the old content, I was not able to see the change because the newly added content was hidden in container. (please update your post, I will accept your post as answer). :)